# How to regroup a nested list with certain criteria?

Tags: python, list, function

I tried to make some linear connection and I have some list:

```
cs = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,6,7],[3,4,5,6]]

b = [1,2,0,2,0,1,2]
```

I first regroup `b` as `bb`

```
bb = [[1,2],[0,2],[0,1,2]]
```

And I tried to regroup `bb` again, the criteria is when 
`cs[u[i]][u[i+1]] > 3`, regroup it as another sublist.

`u` is the sublist in `bb`

`i` is the index of `u`

So the desire output is:

```
output = [[1],[2],[0,2],[0,1],[2]]
```

For the first sublist in `bb`, `cs[1][2]` =4 and >3 , so regroup it as `[1],[2]`

For the third sublist in `bb`, `cs[0][1] < 3 and cs[1][2] >3`, so regroup it as
`[0,1],[2]`

How to get `output` in python?

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this should get the job done for you:

```
cs = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,6,7],[3,4,5,6]]
bb = [[1,2],[0,2],[0,1,2]]
# Make a copy of bb
cc = bb.copy()
# Set an index offset
ci = 0
# Iterate through list bb and alter cc if condition is met
for i in range(len(bb)):
    for j in range(len(bb[i])-1):
        if cs[bb[i][j]][bb[i][j+1]]>3:
# Insert the latter part of bb[i] at i+ci+1 before changing the value at i+ci 
            cc.insert(i+ci+1, bb[i][j+1:])
            cc[i+ci] = list(bb[i][:j+1])
# Increase the index offset by 1
            ci+=1
cc
```

The output I got from this was:
`[[1], [2], [0, 2], [0, 1], [2]]`